# Can't create VM from Kubuntu 16.1: "Unable to find a medium containing a live file system"

Tags: virtualization

As the title says, I'm trying to create a new VM from the Kubuntu 16.1 iso image I downloaded. A few minutes into the process the installation fails with the error:

```
(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

I'm running VMWare Workstation 12 Pro version 12.5.0build-4352439

I was able to create a 14.1 VM using the image I downloaded, so it makes me think this is potentially a Kubuntu issue, not a VMWare issue. However, all the info I found regarding that error has to do with installing via CD/DVD drives or USB drives and aren't applicable to a VMWare installation with an ISO. Has anybody else run into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chripallo's answer is correct: VMware's "Easy Install" feature is causing the issue. I'll detail Chripallo's answer a bit below.

1. Create a virtual machine selecting `I will install the operating system later.`:

[image]

2. After the virtual machine is created, select the image of the operating system  you want to install:

[image]

[image]

3. Start the virtual machine, and install the operating  system.

The answer was tested with  Kubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 and VMware Workstation Pro 14.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very sorry that nobody was able to answer you then. I had this same issue and Googled it, but nothing popped up. I did, however, figure out the solution thanks to an offhanded comment on a Reddit post.

Kubuntu, among other distros, does NOT like VMware's "Easy Install" feature, so you will need to get around that. What I did was select the "I will install the operating system later" option during the creation of the VM. If you already have the VM created, just remove the autostart.iso that it has connected to your VM's drives in "Removable Devices."

Hope that helps anyone who comes across this post in the future.